# Streaming Using Video View works fine but after playing some video Gives Dialog Can Not Play this video

Tags: android

I am using Video View To stream Video.

I am able to start video successfully But what happens is after playing some video I am getting Dialog Box saying Can not play this video.

When I tried multiple times then I realized that It shows  me dialog at random length of video played.

I don't able to find why this is happening.

Comment: I happen to have this problem too.. Did you find out what was causing it?

Comment: I didn't find anything. Most probably internet or streaming error